# how to add dynamic array of textviews to a tablelayout through table row in android?

Tags: android, json

I have been trying to add array of text views in a table layout through table rows but the app stops working .

when I try doing the same in other app it works but when I implement it it my current app when I m fetching the data through JSON, it doesn't create textviews dynamically.

below is my code:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {


                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_a);

                    TextView[] tx = new TextView[items.length()];
                    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[items.length()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String category = c.getString(TAG_Cat);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_Name);

                    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    tx[i] = new TextView(S1.this);
                    tx[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tx[i].setText(category);

                    tr[i] = new TableRow(S1.this);
                    tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tr[i].addView(tx[i],new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    Log.d("d", category);

                    tl.addView(tr[i],new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

                    item.put(TAG_Name, name);
                    itemList.add(item);                         



                }
```

here TAG_a is : private static final String TAG_a = "menu";

here TAG_Name is : private static final String TAG_Name = "Name";

itemList is : ArrayList> itemList;

the url I m using as an api is : "http://ashapurasoftech.com/train/test.json".

I have kept a log in my code so as I can know what comes in my category string. Now when I run the logcat it displays :"d"  Assorted Beverages

My Logcat:

```
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only  the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6006)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:822)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.widget.TableLayout.requestLayout(TableLayout.java:230)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3413)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:420)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at com.app.crossdine.S1$Getitems.doInBackground(S1.java:157)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at com.app.crossdine.S1$Getitems.doInBackground(S1.java:1)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 04-14 03:20:56.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: you are re-creating the arrays each time through the loop? maybe these lines belong before the loop: `TextView[] tx = new TextView[items.length()];TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[items.length()];`

Comment: i changed it and I placed the textview and tableRow outside the for loop. bt it throws exception n my stops working. See my edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception makes sense, an AsyncTask must not do UI operations from doInBackground. You have to publishProgress() and pass whatever parameters you want; this results in your AsyncTask getting called in OnProgressUpdate with your parameters, but in this method you are on UI thread and can do operations like addView().

Comment: m all new to android but cn u plz give me a guide on how to use publishProgress() in my code.

Comment: Google developer training doc at http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html is a good start. It's not complicated, read an example and try it.