# how to split data of AsyncTask of onpostexecute method into array

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to split data so I can display it in different textView

as I given in the image data need to display into these different textview
I'm able to get the data in one textview but not in more than one textviews

**php Code :**

```
 <?php
    require "init.php";
    $user_name=$_POST["login_name"];
    $user_pass=$_POST["login_pass"];

    $sql = "SELECT name,user_name,PRN,cast,dob,admission_category,nationality,permnent_address,local_address,roll_no,class,sub_cast,birth_place,mobile_no,email,branch  FROM user_info where user_name like '$user_name'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "name: " . $row["name"];

      }
    } else {[enter image description here][1]
        echo "login failed try again";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>*
```

**ImportFragment.java**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView imageView2,imageView7;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, container, false);
        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
        String name = i.getStringExtra("sey");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "welcome: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        imageView2 = (ImageView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        TextView textView=(TextView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        textView.setText(name);
        db=this.getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("tedt.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists tb (a blob)");

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from tb",null);
        getImage();
        if(c.moveToNext())
        {
            byte[] image =c.getBlob(0);
            Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"get success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Button button=(Button)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentframe,new ExportFragment()).commit();

            }
        });

    return myInflatedView;
    }

    public void getImage()
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from tb",null);
        if(c.moveToNext())
        {
            byte[] image =c.getBlob(0);
            Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"get success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**BackgroundTask**

```
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        TextView textView1;

        Context ctx;
        BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
        {
            this.textView1=textView1;
            this.ctx=ctx;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information...");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(result.equals("registration success")) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
               // alertDialog.setMessage(result);
               // alertDialog.show();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(ctx,drawer.class);
               intent.putExtra("sey",result);
               String a=result;
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String reg_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
            String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";

            String method=params[0];
            if(method.equals("register"))
            {
                String name=params[1];
                String user_name=params[2];
                String user_pass=params[3];
                try {
                    URL url=new URL(reg_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream os=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                    String data= URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+ "="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                            URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+ "="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                            URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+ "="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    os.close();
                    InputStream is=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    is.close();
                    return "registration success";
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(method.equals("login"))
            {

                String login_name=params[1];
                String login_pass=params[2];
                try {
                    URL url=new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                    String data=URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                            URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String response="";
                    String line="";
                    while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        response+=line;
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return response;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the data length and structure are unknown**

You can display it like the following.

1. The data should be structured like (XML, Json)

   {
   "Name":"Thomas",
   "Age":12,
   "Address":"London"
   }

Every elements should be included a key so that you can generate the TextView (for label) by using the key.

2. The TextView will be generate in a dynamic way since the data length is dynamic in the json data. (Just like this [how to add dynamic array of textviews to a tablelayout through table row in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052867/how-to-add-dynamic-array-of-textviews-to-a-tablelayout-through-table-row-in-andr))

But remember, if there is no any custom-style for some data shown in the android. The layout will not only be ugly but also unreadable. Might be vulnerable if all the data from the server (including the item id or sensitive information of the server) are shown on the mobile. For the best usage of data and your safety, you should fetch your data into each textview one by one(findViewById). If this method is a big trouble to you, you can say goodbye to it and use the android data-binding(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html). 
However, this library is not compatible with JDK 8 yet. Think twice before you use it.